# Rails: get all field for an object coming from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an `Foo` `ActiveRecord` model with fields `foo_id`, `foo_name` and `foo_description`.

After doing something like

```
@foo = Foo.find(1)
```

Is there any method "`model_fields`" such that: `@foo.model_fields()` would return the array:

```
["foo_id", "foo_name", "foo_description"] ?
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is an `attributes` method that give a hash of field and values. So you could use

```
@foo.attributes.keys
```

To get an array of the fields on the model.

There's also a `Foo.column_names` class method that gives you the same information without having to look up a record first.

Documentation for:
[ActiveRecord::Base.column_names](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-column_names)
[ActiveRecord::Base#attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes)

Comment: Thanks Emily for the  quick answer! I am using .attributes= all the time. Not sure why I didn't think about that...

Comment: And if you need to loop through attributes and values, it's simple to do so with a block: `@foo.attributes.each do |k,v|`

Comment: Sometimes I need the column names as symbols, `Model.column_names.map(&:to_sym)` to the rescue.