# save information from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hi everyone at this time i have two tables:

clientesultimasgestiones
clientesgestiones

And I want to put the whole information from clientesgestiones to clientesultimasgestiones but I want to save it field by field, at this momento I have this

```
cnx = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
cnx.execute("truncate table clientesultimasgestiones")
@informacion = Clientesgestion.all

    @informacion.each do |f|
        @clientesultimasgestion = Clientesultimasgestion.new
        @clientesultimasgestion.save(f)
        Here will be the code to save field by field from clientesgestiones table to the another one
    end
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Finally i did it this way:

```
    cnx.execute("truncate table clientesultimasgestiones")
    @informacion = Clientesgestion.all

    @informacion.each do |f|
        l                               = Clientesultimasgestion.new
        l.persona_id                    = f.persona_id
        l.fecha_gestion                 = f.fecha_gestion
        l.clientestipologia_id          = f.clientestipologia_id
        l.observacion                   = f.observacion
        l.user_id                       = f.user_id
        l.fecha_acuerdo                 = f.fecha_acuerdo
        l.valor_apagar                  = f.valor_apagar
        l.clientestipologiaanterior_id  = f.clientestipologiaanterior_id
        l.clientesobligacion_id         = f.clientesobligacion_id
        l.save

    end
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can save a lot of lines with `update_attributes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace:

```
    @clientesultimasgestion.save(f)
```

with:

```
    @clientesultimasgestion.update_attibutes(f.attributes)
```

Also, seems what you want is to copy a table, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237661/1197775.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011140/rails-get-all-field-for-an-object-coming-from-the-database) will help you to get lists of attributes and values.

After this, you need to set dynamically fields, for this purpose you can use method [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send). Something like this: 
    `@clientesultimasgestion.send("#{field_name}=",field_value)`